# python: sorting a dict of dicts on a key

Tags: python

A data structure like this.

```
{
  'ford': {'count': 3},
  'mazda': {'count': 0},
  'toyota': {'count': 1}
 }
```

What's the best way to sort on the value of `count` within the values of the top-level dict?

Comment: dictionary is an unordered datatype, it can not be sorted. You can use `collections.OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 11):

```
d = {'ford': {'count': 3},
     'mazda': {'count': 0},
     'toyota': {'count': 1}}

>>> sorted(d.items(), key=lambda (k, v): v['count'])
[('mazda', {'count': 0}), ('toyota', {'count': 1}), ('ford', {'count': 3})]
```

To keep the result as a dictionary, you can used [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> ordered = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda (k, v): v['count']))
>>> ordered
OrderedDict([('mazda', {'count': 0}), ('toyota', {'count': 1}), ('ford', {'count': 3})])
>>> ordered.keys()          # this is guaranteed to come back in the sorted order
['mazda', 'toyota', 'ford']
>>> ordered['mazda']        # still a dictionary
{'count': 0}
```

Version concerns:

- On Python 2.x you could use `d.iteritems()` instead of `d.items()` for better memory efficiency
- `collections.OrderedDict` is only available on Python 2.7 and Python 3.2 (and higher)

Answer (score 2):

A dicitonary is an unordered data structure, so it cannot be sorted.  You could create a sorted list (or, in Python 2.7, an `OrderedDict`) from your dictionary `d`:

```
sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda item: item[1]["count"])
```

This list can be used as constructor argument for a `collections.OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 0):

An even cleaner way would be to use itemgetter and then use the value to build an ordered dict as the other suggested.

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted(s,key=itemgetter,reverse=True)
['ford', 'toyota', 'mazda']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort the dictionary by some item in the value, the result you cannot preserve as a dict, because in dict the order of the element addition is not preserved. Fot that you have to use OrderedDict. One solution is, once sorted, generate an OrderedDict out of the list of (key,value) tuples.

```
>>> collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.iteritems(),key=lambda x:x[1]["count"],reverse=True))
OrderedDict([('ford', {'count': 3}), ('toyota', {'count': 1}), ('mazda', {'count': 0})])
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a **dict** is a **hash table**, so one can't actually sort it. Try storing the sorted values into a list, which *can* be sorted:

```
l = []
for x in sorted(dictionary.keys()):
    l.append([dictionary[x]])
```

If you really want to keep the keys, maybe add them to the list as well. Just make sure that when accessing the list, even indices (0,2,4,...) are keys and odd indices are values (1,3,5,...)

Answer (score 0):

If the dict you have is named x, then you can get a list of the keys:
sorted_x = sorted(x, key=lambda a: x[a]['count'])
where sorted_x is:
['mazda', 'toyota', 'ford']

Then you can print:
for i in sorted_x:
    print x[i]

Result:
{'count': 0}
{'count': 1}
{'count': 3}